# Sum over product of scalar products with indicator functions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, inner-products, brownian-motion

Let $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the Haar orthonormal basis. In our script we have the following equation as part of a proof for the existence of a Brownian Motion:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \langle h_n , \mathbb{1}_{[0,t]} \rangle \langle h_n, \mathbb{1}_{[0,s]} \rangle = \langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}, \mathbb{1}_{[0,s]} \rangle $

Where the brackets represent the standard $L_2$ scalar product (i.e. integral over $\Omega$) and $s < t$ are in an intervall $[0, T]\subset \mathbb{R}$. I know of this equation for general orthonormal basis:

$x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \langle x, h_n \rangle h_n$

But I still can't figure out what happened here. This might be an error in the script but I can't tell. Can someone clarify please?

Comment: Can you please define $s$?

Comment: I corrected it, hope it is now clear

Comment: It is. Thank you!

Comment: Try to prove that for any inner product space we have that $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x , e_n \rangle \langle y ,e_n\rangle$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the right hand side in your first identity should read $\langle 1_{[0,t]}, 1_{[0,s]}\rangle$, not $\langle 1_{[0,t]}, 1_{[0,t]}\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. You are right it was supposed to be an s. I corrected it.
@rubikscube09 I don't know how to solve it for a general inner product space either

Answer (score 1):

Choose $x = 1_{[0, t]}$ and scalarly mutiply your "known" equation by $x$:
$$
\langle x, x \rangle = \left \langle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \langle x_n, h_n \rangle h_n, x\right \rangle
$$
We use continuity of the scalar product:
$$
\left \langle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \langle x_n, h_n \rangle h_n, x\right \rangle = \left \langle \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^m \langle x_n, h_n \rangle h_n, x\right \rangle = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left \langle \sum_{n = 1}^m \langle x_n, h_n \rangle h_n, x \right \rangle = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^m \langle \langle x_n, h_n \rangle h_n, x \rangle = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^m \langle x_n, h_n \rangle \langle x_n, h_n \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \langle x_n, h_n \rangle \langle x_n, h_n \rangle
$$
(The last sum exists in $\mathbb{R}$ according to Bessel's inequality.)

Comment: Sorry, I updated this to late. I like your proof but Cameron Williams was right, the latter t was supposed to be an s in the equation. Thank you for this though!

Comment: @lpnorm,  OK, but this answer may trivially be adapted for your new version of the question.

Comment: @Ruy Ah yes, I checked it and one can use bilinearity and the fact that
$\langle h_n, h_m \rangle = \delta_{nm}$ 

starting from $\langle x, y \rangle$.